# laravel eager load through model

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables with this relationship:

- User (hasOne store, hasMany products)
- Product (Belongs to user)
- Store (belongs to user)

Now if I want get user products inside user store currently i do this:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $store = Store::findOrFail($id);
        $products = Product::where('user_id', $store->user_id)->get();
        return view('admin.stores.show', compact('store', 'products'));
    }
```

But what I'd like to have is something like:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $store = Store::where('id', $id)->with('products')->first();
        return view('admin.stores.show', compact('store'));
    }
```

## Question

How can I make relation between `products` and `stores` due to their `user_id` column to avoid this line:

```
$products = Product::where('user_id', $store->user_id)->get();
```

Comment: Try this ```$store = Store::where('id', $id)->with('users.products')->first();```

Comment: @shihab ok that returns the data but isn't there any cleaner way? because now i have to loop products like `@foreach($store->user->products as $product)` can't be like `@foreach($store->products as $product)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should add relationship between `Store` and `Product`. Add this to `Store` model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

and this to `Product`:

```
public function store()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Store::class, 'user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: Ok would work but you need to edit your answer `1` is `products()` not `product()` as is `hasMany` `2`  it needs second `'user_id'` same as the one in products model then it'll work